# Why is the button switching the order in the html and javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html

Why is the button switching the order in the html and javascript code? So both buttons are working but the student portal button when pressed switches the order of the display around. I do not understand why can someone look at my code and point out why?

When both status's are at no issue the educator button works fine but the student button switches the order.

If the educator portal is at ISSUE. The student portal button works fine.

If the student portal is at ISSUE. The educator portal switches up the order.

Please Help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").on('click', function(){
    $("#Student_Portal_No_Issue").toggle();
    $("#Student_Portal_Issue").toggle();
  })
})

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn2").on('click', function(){
    $("#Educator_Portal_No_Issue").toggle();
    $("#Educator_Portal_Issue").toggle();
  })
})
</script>

<style>
#Student_Portal_No_Issue{
  display: block
 }
 
#Student_Portal_Issue{
  display: none
 }
 #Educator_Portal_No_Issue{
  display: block
 }
 
#Educator_Portal_Issue{
  display: none
 }
</style>
<body>
<!-- ******************************************Refresh************************************* -->

   <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="6000">



<!-- ******************************************BUTTON************************************* -->
    <button id="btn" type="button"value= "edit">Switch Student Portal Status</button>
        <button id="btn2" type="button"value= "edit">Switch Educator Portal Status</button>
    

<p>


<!--/************************************** No Issue Style***********************************/ -->

  <div id ="Student_Portal_No_Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">


    <div id="Stu_No_Iss" style="float:left; width:48%;">  
      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-
                bottom:10px;"><strong><font size="6">Student Portal</font></strong></p>


      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
        <strong><img alt="" src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/J/t/o/U/t/blue-thumbs-up-md.png" 
                     style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
        <Strong><font size="6">Status: No Issue</font></Strong></p>


      <p style="padding-right:2px; padding-left:5px; text-
                align:left;"><font size="5"><strong>Student Portal is operating 
        normally.</strong></font></p>
    </div>
        <div style="float: left; border-right:1px solid black; 
                height:280px;padding-right:5px;">
      <strong>&nbsp;</strong>
    </div>
</div>










  <div id ="Educator_Portal_No_Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">


    <div id="Ed_No_Iss" style="float:left; width:48%;">  
      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-
                bottom:10px;"><strong><font size="6">Educator Portal</font></strong></p>


      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
        <strong><img alt="" src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/J/t/o/U/t/blue-thumbs-up-md.png" 
                     style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
        <Strong><font size="6">Status: No Issue</font></Strong></p>


      <p style="padding-right:2px; padding-left:5px; text-
                align:left;"><font size="5"><strong>Educator Portal is operating 
        normally.</strong></font></p>
    </div>

</div>







<!--//**************************************Issue Style*********************************** -->
  <div id ="Student_Portal_Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">


    <div id="Iss" style="float:left; width:48%;">  
    
      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-
                bottom:10px;"><strong><font size="6">Student Portal</font></strong></p>

      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
        <img alt=""    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg/240px- Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg.png"
             style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
          <Strong><font size="6">Status: Issue</font></Strong>
                </p>

      <p style="padding-right:2px; padding-left:5px; text-
                align:left;"><font size="5"><strong>Student Portal is experiencing 
        dificulties.</strong></font></p>
        
        </div>
                <div style="float: left; border-right:1px solid black; 
                height:280px;padding-right:5px;">
      <strong>&nbsp;</strong>
    </div>
    </div>






  <div id ="Educator_Portal_Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">


    <div id="Ed_Iss" style="float:left; width:48%;">  
    
      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-
                bottom:10px;"><strong><font size="6">Educator Portal</font></strong></p>

      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
        <img alt=""    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg/240px- Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg.png"
             style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
          <Strong><font size="6">Status: Issue</font></Strong>
                </p>

      <p style="padding-right:2px; padding-left:5px; text-
                align:left;"><font size="5"><strong>Educator Portal is experiencing 
        dificulties.</strong></font></p>
        
        </div>
    </div>








</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't block up all the issues at the end as it causes the order to change. See this example demonstrating what happens when you click the student-issue button (`#btn1`).

```
When the order is:
[student][educator][student-issue][educator-issue]

[student][educator] BECOMES => [educator][student-issue]

When the order is:
[student][student-issue][educator][educator-issue]


[student][educator] BECOMES => [student-issue][educator]
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").on('click', function(){
    $("#Student_Portal_No_Issue").toggle();
    $("#Student_Portal_Issue").toggle();
  })
})

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn2").on('click', function(){
    $("#Educator_Portal_No_Issue").toggle();
    $("#Educator_Portal_Issue").toggle();
  })
})
```

```css
#Student_Portal_No_Issue{
  display: block
 }
 
#Student_Portal_Issue{
  display: none
 }
 #Educator_Portal_No_Issue{
  display: block
 }
 
#Educator_Portal_Issue{
  display: none
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- ******************************************BUTTON************************************* -->
<button id="btn" type="button" value="edit">Switch Student Portal Status</button>
<button id="btn2" type="button" value="edit">Switch Educator Portal Status</button>

<p>

    <!--/************************************** No Issue Style***********************************/ -->

    <div id="Student_Portal_No_Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">

        <div id="Stu_No_Iss" style="float:left; width:48%;">
            <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-
                bottom:10px;"><strong><font size="6">Student Portal</font></strong></p>

            <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
                <strong><img alt="" src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/J/t/o/U/t/blue-thumbs-up-md.png" 
                     style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
        <Strong><font size="6">Status: No Issue</font></Strong></p>

            <p style="padding-right:2px; padding-left:5px; text-
                align:left;"><font size="5"><strong>Student Portal is operating 
        normally.</strong></font></p>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; border-right:1px solid black; 
                height:280px;padding-right:5px;">
            <strong>&nbsp;</strong>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Student_Portal_Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">

        <div id="Iss" style="float:left; width:48%;">

            <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-
                bottom:10px;"><strong><font size="6">Student Portal</font></strong></p>

            <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
                <img alt="" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg/240px- Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg.png" style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
                <Strong><font size="6">Status: Issue</font></Strong>
            </p>

            <p style="padding-right:2px; padding-left:5px; text-
                align:left;"><font size="5"><strong>Student Portal is experiencing 
        dificulties.</strong></font></p>

        </div>
        <div style="float: left; border-right:1px solid black; 
                height:280px;padding-right:5px;">
            <strong>&nbsp;</strong>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Educator_Portal_No_Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">

        <div id="Ed_No_Iss" style="float:left; width:48%;">
            <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-
                bottom:10px;"><strong><font size="6">Educator Portal</font></strong></p>

            <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
                <strong><img alt="" src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/J/t/o/U/t/blue-thumbs-up-md.png" 
                     style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
        <Strong><font size="6">Status: No Issue</font></Strong></p>

            <p style="padding-right:2px; padding-left:5px; text-
                align:left;"><font size="5"><strong>Educator Portal is operating 
        normally.</strong></font></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="Educator_Portal_Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">

        <div id="Ed_Iss" style="float:left; width:48%;">

            <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-
                bottom:10px;"><strong><font size="6">Educator Portal</font></strong></p>

            <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
                <img alt="" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg/240px- Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg.png" style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
                <Strong><font size="6">Status: Issue</font></Strong>
            </p>

            <p style="padding-right:2px; padding-left:5px; text-
                align:left;"><font size="5"><strong>Educator Portal is experiencing 
        dificulties.</strong></font></p>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help